# Trouble with Game of Life and dynamic arrays, c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic, conways-game-of-life

I am trying to program the game of life. When I attempt to iterate generations I end up with garbage. I have tried quite a few different things but I don't see my error, but obviously there is one. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm almost certain I'm doing something wrong when I try to apply the logic of the game to the old array, to create the new one, but I'm not sure what. This is one of four functions, I have tested the others and I am positive the flaw lies within this one. The end goal is to have the game expand and shrink as necessary with each generation.

```
void iterateGeneration ()
{
ifstream fin;
fin.open("tmp.txt");
ofstream fout;

char **arr=new char * [ROWS];
for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    arr[i] = new char [COLUMNS];

int lifecheck=0;
//read in current generation from tmp.txt
for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
    fin.getline(arr[i], COLUMNS);
    }
fin.close();

char **new_arr=new char * [ROWS];
for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    new_arr[i]= new char [COLUMNS];

//count live neighbors, then determine if cell will be alive next generation
for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
    for(int j=0; j<COLUMNS-1; j++)
        {
        lifecheck=0;
        if((i==0 && j==0) || (i==0 && j==(COLUMNS-2)) || (i==(ROWS-1) && j==0) ||     (i==(ROWS-1) && j==(COLUMNS-2)))//corners always stay dead
            {
            lifecheck=0;
            }
        else if(i==0)//special check for first row, only three checks since neighbors     in first row is always dead
            {
            if(arr[i+1][j-1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i+1][j]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i+1][j+1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            }
        else if(i==(ROWS-1))//special check for last row
            {
            if(arr[i-1][j-1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i-1][j]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i-1][j+1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            }
        else if(j==0)//special check for first column
            {
            if(arr[i-1][j+1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i][j+1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i+1][j+1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            }
        else if(j==(COLUMNS-2))//special check for last column
            {
            if(arr[i-1][j-1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i][j-1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i+1][j-1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            }
        else
            {
            if(arr[i-1][j-1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i-1][j]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i-1][j+1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i][j-1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i][j+1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i+1][j-1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i+1][j]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            if(arr[i+1][j+1]=='1')
                lifecheck+=1;
            }
        if(arr[i][j]=='0')
            {
            if(lifecheck==3)
                new_arr[i][j]=='1';
            else
                new_arr[i][j]=='0';
            }
        else if(arr[i][j]=='1')
            {
            if(lifecheck==2)
                new_arr[i][j]=='1';
            else if(lifecheck==3)
                new_arr[i][j]=='1';
            else
                new_arr[i][j]=='0';
            }

        else
            new_arr[i][j]=='0';
        }//2nd for
    }//1st for

fout.open("tmp.txt");

for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
    fout << new_arr[i];
    fout << endl;
    }

for(int p=0; p<ROWS; p++)
    {
    delete [] arr[p];
    delete [] new_arr[p];
    }
delete [] arr;
delete [] new_arr;
}


using namespace std;

const int NUM_GENERATIONS = 1; //set to a smaller number for debugging

int main() 
{
    populateWorld(FILE_NAME);

    showWorld();

    for (int iteration = 0; iteration < NUM_GENERATIONS; iteration++) 
    {

        if (WINDOWS)
           system("cls"); //Windows only
        else
           system("clear"); //Linux only

        iterateGeneration();

        showWorld();
    } 

    if (WINDOWS)
        system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000001010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000011000000110000000000001100000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000100010000110000000000001100000000000000000000000110000000
0000000011000000001000001000110000000000000000000000000000000000000110000000
0000000011000000001000101100001010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000001000001000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000100010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001110000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010001000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000100000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000100000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010001000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001110000000
0000011000000000000000111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000
0000011000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011100000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011100000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100010000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001100011000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0001100011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000100010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000011100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000011100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010000000000000001100000
0000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000001110000000000000001100000
0000000111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000001000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000010000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000010000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000001000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001100000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100010000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000001000001000000001100000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101000011010001000000001100000000
0000000110000000000000000000000011000000000000110001000001000000000000000000
0000000110000000000000000000000011000000000000110000100010000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000001100000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00`ó!#\00\00 \00\00
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000010
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000110000001100000000000011000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000001100000000000011000000000000000000000001
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000000000000110000000
00000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000
00000000000000000010000010
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000001000100000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000100010000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000100000100000
00000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000100000
00000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000000000000100000000
00000110
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000
00000000000000000000001100
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000000000000000000100010000
00
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\001000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000
00001000100000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000110000000000000000000000
00000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000001100000
00000000100000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000001110000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000000000
00000100000100000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000
00000010001000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000001000100000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000100000001000001000000001100000000
00000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000001100000000
00000001100000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000001100000000000000000000000110000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0000000000000000000000000000001100000011000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000101000000000000000000000000000000
00
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
x"#\00\00x"#\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\000000
```

Comment: Define "garbage", please. You're also using a highly unorthodox indentation style.

Comment: Why does everyone insist on making their lives more difficult by manually managing their memory?

Comment: "Garbage" xã_
xã_
xã_ that is what I'm getting as output after the copy. Sorry for the weird indentation.

Comment: please provide your main()

Comment: please provide tmp.txt

Comment: main is up... will upload the file it reads from to start as well as tmp.txt

Comment: The driver file with main() as well as the file that I read from to start is posted below iterategeneration() in the code also I am only managing my own memory because I was interested in learning how it is done. I'm aware there are much easier ways <vector> for one, but I'm mostly doing this for fun, and learning.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly output each character of the array not the entire array of characters.

I believe fprintf will output an array like how you want but it has been a long time since I used c++. Probably not since writing a very very similar program in high school.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you save `new_arr`:

```
for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
    fout << new_arr[i];
    fout << endl;
    }
```

And here, specifically, is the bug:

```
    fout << new_arr[i];
```

Sending a `char *` to an `ostream` will send successive characters until the "null terminator" `'\0'` character is found.

Your code never sets a null terminator, so it's very difficult to tell how much is being written.  Based on your garbage results, it's too much.

Comment: I will try to output char by char and let you know

Comment: @user1768079 that should do the job, since you already know how many characters you want to output.

Comment: What ever is happening it is writing the correct number of lines, just their content is bad. There are 61 lines in the input file, and 61 in the output file. The ouput "tmp.txt" should be 0's and 1's just like the input file, just changed based on the rules of the game.

Comment: It's kind of working now. I'm getting some 1's and 0's. I'll copy tmp.txt below the input file at the very bottom of the OP.

Comment: The only thing I can think, is that some of the time it's leaving the array blank because the logic in the if statements is bad, and so when it works, and writes I'm getting what I should, but the rest of the time I'm getting what was already in that area of the memory.